# python function change hyperparameter name

Tags: python, function

```
def wklearnerExp(hyparam="max_depth"):
    param = np.arange(1,200, 5)
    for p in param:
        wkClf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=p) # Change max_depth to a hyparam defined  at hyparam="max_depth"
```

For the funciton above, would it be possible to change the hyperparameter name **"max_depth"** to something else, such as "min_samples_leaf"? So that I can do:

```
wklearnerExp(hyparam="min_samples_leaf")
```

and swap the hyper parameter in the function while not rewrite the whole code again.

I've tried the following but not working

```
wkClf = DecisionTreeClassifier(eval(hyparam)=p)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to pass the name of a variable you want to change to a function as a string. What are you trying to achieve that you think needs this type of solution? It's not impossible by any stretch, but there's most likely a simpler and better solution to your actual problem. Where it makes sense, the classes involved will expose hyperparamaters as a dictionary, or similarly indexable datastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
def wklearnerExp(hyparam="max_depth"):
    param = np.arange(1,200, 5)
    for p in param:
        wkClf = DecisionTreeClassifier(**{hyparam: p})
```

The `**` operator converts a dictionary to keyword arguments.  Whether it is a good idea or not is debatable.